# Asymmetric Subspace Optimization (ASO)

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying  to implement the ASO for the Sellar problem but the "subproblem" is not working as I expected. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Although the Sellar problem is not a good example to understand the ASO architecture (both disciplines have pretty much the same computational cost), it's a simple formulation and I'm using it as a benchmark before trying to use in the problem I'm studying. 
My code is( OpenMDAO 1.7):

```
class low_order(Group):

 def __init__(self):
    super(low_order, self).__init__()

    self.add('plx', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
    self.add('plz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['z'])


    self.add('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes=['x', 'z', 'y1', 'y2'])
    #self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['z', 'y1', 'y2'])

    self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                 z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]) ),
             promotes=['obj', 'x', 'z', 'y1', 'y2'])

    self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['con1', 'y1'])


    self.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    self.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'  


class SellarDerivatives(Group):


 def __init__(self):
    super(SellarDerivatives, self).__init__()

    self.add('ppx', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
    self.add('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['z'])


    self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['z', 'y1', 'y2'])

    self.add('obj_cmp1', ExecComp('obj1 = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                 z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]) ),
             promotes=['obj1', 'x', 'z', 'y1', 'y2'])

    #self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['con1', 'y1'])
    self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['con2', 'y2'])

    self.nl_solver = NLGaussSeidel()
    self.nl_solver.options['atol'] = 1.0e-12
    self.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()


    self.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    self.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'


if __name__ == '__main__':

from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizer, SqliteRecorder



sub = Problem()
sub.root = low_order()
sub.driver =ScipyOptimizer()# pyOptSparseDriver()
sub.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
sub.driver.options['disp'] = False


sub.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

sub.driver.add_objective('obj')
sub.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
#sub.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)



top = Problem()
top.root = SellarDerivatives()

top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()#pyOptSparseDriver()
top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'



top.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),
                     upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]))


top.root.add('subprob1', SubProblem(sub, params=['z'],unknowns=['y1','x'])) 


top.root.connect('z','subprob1.z')



top.driver.add_objective('obj1')
#top.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)


top.setup()
top.run()
```

When I look the iterations, I see that only the Z1 and Z2 are varying as I expected, and I have no idea about the X. 
The lines below are : X | Z1 | Z2

```
(8.881784197001252e-16, 5.000916977558285, 1.000912901563544)
(1.0000000008881784e-06, 5.000916977558285, 1.000912901563544)
(-9.999999991118215e-07, 5.000916977558285, 1.000912901563544)
(8.881784197001252e-16, 5.000912478379066, 1.0009120015635442)
(8.881784197001252e-16, 5.000912478379066, 1.0009120015635442)
(1.0000000008881784e-06, 5.000912478379066, 1.0009120015635442)
(-9.999999991118215e-07, 5.000912478379066, 1.0009120015635442)
```

And the final answer is ( Z1 , Z2 , X ):

```
Minimum found at (5.000912, 1.000912, 1.000000)
Coupling vars: 0.000000, 6.001824
('Minimum objective: ', 2.0033861370124493)
```

Ps. As the Sellar problem is not my main objective, I'm using FD across the whole model, just to make it easier for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with a few changes (it didn't work at all with the code you sent, but we may have tightened some error checking between 1.7 and 1.7.3.)

You need to pass y2 into the subproblem to complete the cycle:

```
top.root.add('subprob1', SubProblem(sub, params=['z', 'y2'], unknowns=['y1', 'x']), promotes=['*'])
```

And you need to remove the extra IndepVarComp for variable 'x' in the top "SellarDerivatives" group because you are letting the subproblem be the ultimate source.

```
#self.add('ppx', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
```

With those changes and using pyoptsparse, I get for the sub:

```
Objectives:
    Name        Value        Optimum
    obj        3.18339             0

Variables (c - continuous, i - integer, d - discrete):
       Name      Type       Value       Lower Bound  Upper Bound
    x_0       c       0.000004       0.00e+00     1.00e+01
```

and for the main problem:

```
Objectives:
    Name        Value        Optimum
    obj1       3.18339             0

Variables (c - continuous, i - integer, d - discrete):
       Name      Type       Value       Lower Bound  Upper Bound
    z_0       c       1.977638      -1.00e+01     1.00e+01 
    z_1       c       0.000000       0.00e+00     1.00e+01
```

Comment: Kenneth, thank you very much!

I had to insert:

    self.add('ply2', IndepVarComp ('y2',.0), promotes = ['y2'])

In the low_order class to make it work, but now it's working!!

I'm not sure why, but if I use the ScipyOptimizer in the SubProblem, it simple does not converge. But using the PyOptSparse, everything works fine. I'm using SLSQP because  I'm still struggling to get SNOPT in my University here in Brazil.

Comment: Hm, I think the SLSQP fortran module in scipy is non-reentrant, which means that if you run two instances of it in the same memory space, they share common blocks, so the inner loop basically tramples on values stored in memory in the outer loop. That would explain why it doesn't work at all with scipy:slsqp in both places.